# Google Play : the requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I recently created an app and launched in Google Play. Yesterday I re-uploaded another version fixing a minor bug. I can see `View on Google Play` text and link next to my app name. But, when I clicked on it I see `We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.` error. I can't see the app on Playstore by searching as well.

Reading some other questions, I noticed this is a rising issue in Google Play developer console in this year, probably after the new console is released. Some say we need to wait till IARC rating is approved, so I checked it as well.

I checked IARC rating for my app as the following. I can't see the IARC rating ID.

[image]

Then I checked the release dashboard, I noticed my first release and the immediate update is still under review.

[image]

So, what is going on here? In my experience, I only see `View on Google Play` link only if the app is available in the playstore.

Here I see `View on Google Play` link, but release dashboard says both updates are in review and IARC does not show the ID, so I suspect it's still pending to be reviewed as well.

What's going on here? Google Play console is now buggy?

Comment: Play store console generates the app public link as soon as you upload the your first release. First release my take 7-10 days in review, I think now they review the app manually.

Comment: Your query regarding IARC rating, I have no idea about it.

Comment: @UmerFarooq Okay. You may post your comment as an answer, so it will be visible with others answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was no issue. Google play URL get available as soon as you published an app. If you navigate into `release` section, you will see the app is `under review`.

Google took around 12 days to review my app

Answer (score 0):

The release status still indicates that your app is in review. I think there is no issue; it is just the review process may sometimes take a while.